# Unable to scrape data after logging into website with Python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a MMA website, then webscrape different user data once logged in.  I've tried a variety of methods to login, inlcuding Selenium, which seem to work.  But after I login, and verify a 200 OK message, the next URL I navigate to does not cache the login, and I get html messages that I need to be signed in to access the URL.  Any suggestions?

```
import requests
from lxml import html



ulist=list()
public=list()
count=0

session_requests = requests.session()

payload = {
    "identities_password[uid]": "username",
    "identities_password[password]": "password",
    "authenticity_token": "<CSRF_TOKEN>"
}

login_url = "https://www.tapology.com/sign_in"
result = session_requests.get(login_url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value")))[0]

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data = payload,
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)

print('logged in')

z=result.status_code
print(z)

#Now go to a page to scrape data

session = requests.session()
result = session.get('https://www.tapology.com/profiles/the%20axe%20murderer/predictions/71715-ufc-255')


for link in result:
    link=link.decode()
    print(link)
    file=open('results.txt', 'w')
    file.write(link)
```

Comment: You're creating a totally new session after you've logged in. Try using the exact same session as before and see if that keeps you authenticated. As in, use `session_request` to actually get the new page.

Comment: If i run session_request again, against the login_url, it does seem to return html indicating i'm logged in.  As soon as i setup a new session_request for the page that i need to scrape information from, it says i'm not logged in.

Comment: You're just overwriting the session once again! What I meant was that the session inside of `session_request` is already authenticated, LITERALLY use that authenticated session to get the other page.

Comment: Any chance you could post a quick example?  I can't figure out where to "nest" the next url.

Comment: Literally, the line after `print('logged in')` in your above code, do your new `result = session_requests.get(<your url here>)`. You don't have to create a new instance of `requests.session()` for each page that you're fetching.

Comment: Your login request does not authenticate you, because you are not setting  `authenticity_token` into `payload`.

Comment: Thank you.  The login request was my issue, it wasn't logging in even though it was sending a 200 OK,